# Sequence Unique Values Within Another Unique Value in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am trying to create a formula that checks Column A for unique values, then takes that value and checks column B for unique values and orders them sequentially in Column C. Column C is the where the formula goes. It's not in the actual data set.

This is what I want my data set to look like.

[image]

For example, I want to find unique Entry Number "123-A. I then want to look within that entry number and find the unique codes in Column B and order them sequentially. The first two are the same, so they both are sequence 1. Then the third row as a new code, "Y09", so it will get sequence 2. Once the next unique entry number is identified, I want to reset the sequential count. Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi, I've tried a formula similar to this,  =IF(COUNTIF(A$2:A2,A2)=1,MAX(B$1:B1)+1,VLOOKUP(A2,A$1:B1,2,0)), but I'm having trouble adapting it to look for unique values within Column B when there are unique value for Column A.

Comment: is the data always sorted like you have shown?

Comment: Column C is what I want the formula to return. It is not in the actual data set. The data is not always sorted this way, I just put it order for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the first thing we want to do is check if a number has *already* been allocated.  Since there are 2 columns to check, we need to use `INDEX MATCH` with an Array Condition instead of just a `VLOOKUP`:

```
INDEX($C$1:$C1, MATCH(1, ($A$1:$A1=$A2)*($B$1:$B1=$B2), 0))
```

These formula are intended for cell C2 - notice how we left the *second* cell in each Range reference without the `$` to lock it in place.  This means it will always stop at the row *above* the formula

If this works, we're done.  If it *doesn't* we get an error - so, we can use `IFERROR`:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($C$1:$C1, MATCH(1, ($A$1:$A1=$A2)*($B$1:$B1=$B2), 0)), ???)
```

On to replacing those question marks!

Since we don't have a match, we need to find the *largest* match for the Entry Number, and add 1 for it.  If you have Office365 or Office2019, we can just use the `MAXIFS` function.  Otherwise, we will have to use `SUMPRODUCT` and `MAX` to get the same result:  (If the Entry Number does not exist, this will return 0)

```
MAXIFS($C$1:$C1, $A$1:$A1, $A2)

SUMPRODUCT(MAX($C$1:$C1 * ($A$1:$A1=$A2)))
```

Then, Add 1:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($C$1:$C1, MATCH(1, ($A$1:$A1=$A2)*($B$1:$B1=$B2), 0)), MAXIFS($C$1:$C1, $A$1:$A1, $A2) + 1)

=IFERROR(INDEX($C$1:$C1, MATCH(1, ($A$1:$A1=$A2)*($B$1:$B1=$B2), 0)), SUMPRODUCT(MAX($C$1:$C1 * ($A$1:$A1=$A2))) + 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your data is already organized/sorted by the column **A** and **B** values.  If this is the case, we can construct a formula implementing the following rules:

1. if the adjacent **A** and **B** values match the values above them, copy down the **C** value from above
2. if the adjacent **A** value matches the value above it, but the **B** value does not, then increment the **C** value from above.
3. If the **A** value does not the value above it, then set the **C** value to 1

In **C2** enter `1`.  In **C3** enter:

```
=IF(AND(A3=A2,B3=B2),C2,IF(A3=A2,C2+1,1))
```

and copy downward:

[image]

if your data is not organized in the same way your picture indicates, then ignore this solution.